# Youtube video different quality between Android Chrome Browser and Webview

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webview, youtube

I have a website www.yatha.tv. It is working very well in Chrome Browser (APP).

Now I am creating the app. Actually just call my website url from webview.

I am using html5webview to fix full screen issue.

https://code.google.com/p/html5webview/

It is working fine as well. But webview is playing with very low quality compare the same video playing in Chrome Browser.

Is this normal or I need to set config in webview.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: I also face the same issue, when switching to FS. The quality is degraded. @Alex, have you found any solution yet?